# How to build a Node.js application with web hosting service?

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

Is it possible to build a node application with a web hosting service, such as blue host, godaddy or media temple? Or does it need to be on a hosting site such as Heroku or Back4App? If so where do I start to learn how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are differentiating "web hosting service" and "hosting site", those aren't really different things as far as I can see.  That said, I'm not a fan of godaddy and haven't ever heard of blue host or media temple (and I've been in this business quite a while).  IF you're just starting out, I'd strongly recommend Heroku as it lets you get going for free while also not pushing you into e.g. Parse framework like back4app does.

Answer (score 2):

"Web hosting" is a pretty broad term, but typically you're going to see static HTML, and some hosted PHP, and a few other technologies.  It's atypical to see Node.js application hosting as part of a general web hosting package.  The reason is that you're going to want more control over the environment in which it runs.

That gives you a couple general classes of options:

### Virtual or Dedicated Hosting

Having a VPS instance, or even a full machine if you can afford it, gives you full access to the OS and what you install on it.  This means you can run whatever you want, including Node.js.  You can get very cheap VPS hosting.

### Node.js Application Hosting

This is the sort of service you get with Heroku or on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  Your application more directly integrates with the hosting provider, allowing you to take advantage of some of their automation and deployment tooling.  If you need to do any automatic scaling, this is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of this five:

- RedHat OpenShift
- Nodejitsu
- Microsoft Azure (don't!, well... try if you want to)
- Modulus
- Heroku (my fauvorite)

You can see details of each one [here](http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/where-to-find-free-node-js-hosting/)! But I would start with heroku app, but it's your choice

To get started with [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)

Comment: Don't forget accept any answer if you found useful!

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy does allow nodejs as part of its "web hosting"  offering:

https://www.godaddy.com/pro/one-click-installation/node-js

That said, I really recommend Heroku and similar services for having less upsell and letting you work closer to cruft-free.